# Generating byte array within Go

Tags: python, go, byte

I am attempting to port some Python code over to Go.

In my Python code I do:

```
print(b"\x02" + (3).to_bytes(4, "big", signed=True))
```

This returns me `[]byte{0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x3}`

This adds 2 to the start of my byte array and then 3 on the end with a prefix of 3 0's.

In GO I'm doing

```
digest = append(digest, byte(0x02))
    err := binary.Write(buf, binary.BigEndian, int64(3))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
digest = append(digest, buf.Bytes()...)
return digest
```

This returns `[]byte{0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x3}`

In Python I can choose the length which seems to be the issue, is there something similar in Go when converting an int to bytes?

Thanks!

Comment: 8 byte is used for int64, you can use int32 for 4 byte. You will find details here https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/

Comment: a 64 bit value is 8 bytes. If you only want 4 bytes, use a 32bit value.

Comment: Thanks both! If you'd like to add this an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like suggested in some comments, too, you can just use a different data type e.g. `int32` instead of `int64`.

```
digest = append(digest, byte(0x02))
    err := binary.Write(buf, binary.BigEndian, int32(3))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
digest = append(digest, buf.Bytes()...)
return digest
```

This will produce the desired outcome `[]byte{0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x3}`.